# Should I enqueue external scripts using wp_enqueue_script()?

Tags: wordpress

It is correct to enqueue external scripts with that function? 
It works but doesn't it slow down opening the site?

```
wp_register_script( 'google-maps', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true', null, null, true );
wp_register_script( 'jsapi', 'https://www.google.com/jsapi', null, null, true );
wp_register_script( 'bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js', null, null, true );
wp_register_script( 'unveil', get_template_directory_uri() . '/new-js/jquery.unveil.min.js', null, null, true );
```

Answer (score 16):

No, it doesn't slow the site (at least not enough to make it a reason for not using it). This is the correct way to enqueue any type of script in WordPress. All this function does is add the proper `<link>` tags (with dependencies) to your HTML `<head>`.

However, for some reason, you haven't included dependencies in your code. For example, Bootstrap requires jQuery, so you should include it in your function:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.5', true );
```

As shown above, you should also consider using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) instead of `wp_register_script()`, since it will save you a step.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. I asked because I have a problem when external scripts slows down the whole page (block other scripts). I have problem with facebook, maps and bootstrap. Is there simple solution for it?