# How to edit load google jquery CDN files instead of WP defualt jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

To Edit default jQuery loading in WORDPRESS,
 How load cdn files from google or other cdn network...

Using a CDN YSlow doesn't recognize? Specify your CDNs in your User Settings.

There are 8 static components that are not on CDN.

```
http://www.climbusengineering.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/genericons/genericons.css?ver=3.4.1
http://www.climbusengineering.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css?ver=4.4.2
http://www.climbusengineering.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3
http://www.climbusengineering.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1
http://www.climbusengineering.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.4.2
http://www.climbusengineering.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js?ver=20151112
http://www.climbusengineering.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/js/functions.js?ver=20151204
http://www.climbusengineering.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.4.2
```

Any wp plugins or script ...
Thanks for advance .!

Comment: Dequeue them, and then enqueue your own from cdn. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35224885/629127) answer that was recently posted by rnevius.

Comment: In your child theme overwrite the theme function that enqueues them